# curl not able to write to /tmp directory owned by user

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, curl, tmp

I tried running the script as instructed in https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh
```

But the script crashed in the following line:

```
curl -L -o docker.tgz "$STATIC_RELEASE_URL"
```

With the message:

```
Warning: Failed to create the file docker.tgz: Permission denied
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```

I narrowed down the problem to `curl` trying to write to the `tmp` folder created by `mktemp -d`, but I don't understand why it fails.

Some context:

```
$ whoami
thiago

$ uname -a
Linux thiago-acer 5.8.0-55-generic #62~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 2 08:55:04 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ mktemp -d
/tmp/tmp.U1nPTN5dlS

$ cd /tmp/tmp.U1nPTN5dlS

$ ls -la
total 8
drwx------  2 thiago thiago 4096 Jun 17 18:20 .
drwxrwxrwt 25 root   root   4096 Jun 17 18:20 ..
```

After running the commands above, I tried:

```
# this fails with the same message as above
curl https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-20.10.7.tgz -O

# this works just fine
curl https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-20.10.7.tgz -o - > docker-20.10.7.tgz

# this also works
wget https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-20.10.7.tgz
```

The `curl -O` command also works if I try it on some other folder, like my home folder.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question to include what `$STATIC_RELEASE_URL` is set to. Also, check your cURL manual (on *your* system, which may differ from versions on the web) for how the -o (lower case letter o) and -O (upper case letter O) options work--and do not confuse them with the -0 (numeric zero) option. Finally, show what the current working directory is for each command. Many cURL commands/options assume the current working directory.

Comment: This is the error when I try it:  "<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>". I suggest you try .https://www.docker.com and see if you can find the correct URL. Also, your URL for curl doesn't look correct if you're trying to download the file "docker.tgz" - and I have no idea why you're piping the curl command into /bin/sh.

Comment: What happens if you do a `touch docker.tgz` after `cd /tmp/tmp.U1nPTN5dlS`? The permissions on `.` look like it *should* work, but apparently it doesn't ...

Comment: @c-m the content of `$STATIC_RELEASE_URL` while running the script is `https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-20.10.7.tgz`. But it is not relevant, since I can reproduce the error by running the command in the shell by passing the full url, as described. I checked the man from curl while writing these tests, and the difference is that -O will write to a file in the current working directory with the same name of file in the url, -o allows you to write to the given path (`-o -` causes the content to be redirect to syrupy).

Comment: @CinaedSimson piping the curl command into /bin/sh is how the docker site I linked recommends to do it. It is an automated installation script, that should be downloaded and executed. I'm not sure why you got a 301... I tested again both `https://get.docker.com/rootless` and `https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-20.10.7.tgz` and they are working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many people this will help, but sharing just in case it helps someone. For me, I had the `Failure writing output to destination` error, but not the `Permission denied` error.

This was due to my `/tmp` dir being full

```
$ df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           7.8G  7.8G     0 100% /tmp
```

Cleaning up my `/tmp` dir resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

That behaviour could be explained if for some reason, the `curl` executable had the setuid bit in its permissions and was owned by  a user other than `root` or `thiago`.

As in:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/bin/curl
-rwsr-xr-x 1 nobody nogroup 260328 Mar 14 16:37 /usr/bin/curl*
```

`curl -o file` would fail because `file` would be `open()ed` by `nobody` who doesn't have write access  to that directory while `curl -o - > file` would work because the  file is opened by the shell, running as `thiago`, not `curl`.

Another possible explanation could be some `apparmor` / SELinux or other MAC security system denying `curl` from creating files in `/tmp`.

System or audit logs should have more information in that case.